# properties of pullback diagrams

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Suppose you have a commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$

$\begin{CD}
A @>>> B\\
@VVV @VVV \\
C @>>> D \\
@VVV @VVV \\
E @>>> F
\end{CD}$

Let $T$ be the top "square", $B$ be the bottom "square", and $R$ be the entire (outer) rectangle.

I'm interested in statements of the form if two of $\{T,B,R\}$ are cartesian, then the other one must be as well.

Certainly if $T,B$ are cartesian, then so is $R$.

What about the other possibilities:

If $T,R$ are cartesian, must $B$ be cartesian?

If $B,R$ are cartesian, must $T$ be cartesian?

I feel like the answer is probably no, though I can't come up with any counterexamples.

Comment: This has been asked before on math.SE.

Comment: Surely it must be difficult to search for questions relating to diagrams?

Comment: Have you tried to prove that either one is correct? I feel like the veracity should reveal itself somehow but typing up diagram chases is not fun.

Comment: What does *cartesian* mean for a commutative diagram?

Comment: This is called the pullback (pasting) lemma.

Comment: @Stefan: for a square, it means it's a pullback square.

Comment: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pullback#Pasting

Comment: @AdeelKhan thanks I found it

Comment: I know this is an old question, but a counterexample for the first part can be found here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237915/counterexample-of-pullback-lemma