# Counterexample of pullback lemma.

Tags: category-theory

I'm looking for a counterexample of the pullback lemma, i.e., a diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{}>> B @>>> C\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
D @>>> E @>>> F
\end{CD}
$$

such that left square and outer square are pullbacks but right square is not a pullback. I have tried hard but I can't find a counterexample.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Reference for "pullback lemma": https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pullback_Lemma

Comment: You don't look for a counterexample of the pullback lemma (it is a proven lemma, it does not have counterexamples), but rahter of the variant that you have mentioned.

Comment: Hint: Look for a diagram of vector spaces where most of the objects are zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a counterexample that works in (almost) any category : let $p:X\to Y$ be a split epimorphism that is not an isomorphism, with section $s:Y\to X$. Then in the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y @>{id_Y}>> Y @>{id_Y}>> Y\\
@V{id_Y}VV @VV{s}V @VV{id_Y}V\\
Y @>>{s}> X @>>_p> Y,
\end{CD}$$
the outer rectangle is a pullback since all its sides are identity maps, the left square is a pullback since $s$ is a monomorphism, but the right square cannot be a pullack if $s$ and $p$ are not isomorphisms.

Alternatively, you can take any monomorphism $m:A\to B$, and form the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{id_A}>> A @>{m}>> B\\
@V{id_A}VV @VV{m}V @VV{id_B}V\\
A @>>{m}> B @>>_{id_B}> B.
\end{CD}$$
Here the left square is a pullback since $m$ is a mono, the rectangle is a pullback, but the right-hand square is not a pullback if $m$ is not an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

The paper [The other pullback lemma](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~mrp/the_other_pullback_lemma.pdf) by Michal Przybylek exactly deals with this kind of situation. The introduction mentions two counterexamples. See also [this mathoverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143070/two-pullback-diagram). There you can also find a very formal counterexample by Eric Wofsey.